# Tensorflow Dropout: What happens if I apply two dropout layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, dropout

Lets say, I am constructing a neural network like so:

```
x = tf.nn.conv2d(input, ...)
x = tf.nn.max_pool(x, ...)
x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=1.)
x = tf.nn.thislayershallhavedropout(x,...)
x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=.5)
```

Would this be an effective technique to tell TensorFlow to just dropout the layer `thislayershallhavedropout`?

Basically, what I am trying to do is to tell TensorFlow to use dropout only on a single layer and not cascade back into earlier layers.

Comment: I'm unclear on the semantics of what you're trying to do.  `dropout` is a layer operation, much like ReLU, pool, or activation.  Dropping (resetting) half the weights doesn't directly affect the weights in previous or successive layers; it's applied at this one point in the forward data flow.  There is no effect on the back-propagation.

Comment: In short, a dropout with 100% keep is a null operation.

Comment: @Prune dropout drops **activations**. dropconnect drops weights.

Comment: Yes what I intend to do is preventing dropout from the earlier layers. But as you and Thomas explain, dropout is applied only at the layer it is applied to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropout sets activations that pass through to `0` with a given chance. It's hard to give a 'layer' dropout, as you are only setting connections to `0` or to `1` with a given chance.

If you want to give the outgoing connections from a certain layers dropout, you should do:

```
x = tf.nn.thislayershallhavedropout(x,...)
x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=.5)
```

Which you have basically done. So 50% percent of the activations coming from `thislayershallhavedropout` will be disactivated.

By the way, as was pointed out in the comments, setting keep_prob to `1` has no effect at all: this will let all activations pass through like normal.

```
x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=1.)
```

Keep in mind: dropout might not directly interfere with previous layers, however, during backpropagation, weights of previous and succesive layers will adapt to half the activations being disabled. Thus, there is no way you can prevent dropout having an (indirect) effect on previous layers.

Comment: OK understood! Would you mind sharing the source of info for your last, highlighted sentence?

Comment: @Ulu83 it was actually a copied comment from your question. I changed it though.